# JavaScript console can see contents of Object but I can't access it

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm trying to use the OpenLayers JavaScript library to load a number of KML files to a map.  I can load all of the KML without a problem, but now in trying to retrieve data from the OpenLayers.Layer.Vector object being generated I'm running in to an issue.

If I output the generated object with console.log I can see the full object with all of it's properties fleshed out, but if I try to access most of the properties programatically I'm getting an undefined error.  Here is my code:

```
    map = new OpenLayers.Map("mapdiv");
    map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());

    var vectors = new Array();

    for(i = 1; i <= 14; i++ ) {

        var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("KML", {
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                url: "kml/" + i + ".kml",
                format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML
            })
        });
        console.log(layer);
        console.log(layer.features[0].attributes.name);

        vectors.push(layer);
    }
    //etc...
```

So with just console.log(layer) I am able to see everything.  With the following line, though, although the information clearly exists, I get the error.  Also, when I try to access the same information directly through the console it works just fine.

Am I missing something obvious here?

EDIT:

Here is the root Object

```
Object:
EVENT_TYPES: Array[25]
alwaysInRange: true
div: HTMLDivElement
drawn: true
events: Object
features: Array[1]
id: "OpenLayers.Layer.Vector_39"
inRange: true
map: Object
maxExtent: Object
maxResolution: 1.40625
maxScale: 13517.573318481445
minExtent: null
minResolution: 0.00004291534423828125
minScale: 442943842.5
name: "KML"
numZoomLevels: 16
options: Object
projection: Object
protocol: Object
renderer: Object
resolutions: Array[16]
scales: Array[16]
selectedFeatures: Array[0]
strategies: Array[1]
styleMap: Object
tileSize: Object
units: "degrees"
unrenderedFeatures: Object
__proto__: Object
```

EDIT 2:

Won't be able to Stringify easily so here is some relevant information:

inside "features":

```
0: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
id: "OpenLayers.Layer.Vector_39"
```

inside "0":

```
attributes: Object
data: Object
geometry: Object
id: "OpenLayers.Feature.Vector_3508"
layer: Object
lonlat: null
renderIntent: "default"
state: null
style: null
inRange: true
```

inside "attributes":

```
name: <string, which I can assure you exists>
```

For clarification the "layer.features[0].attributes.name" that I am attempting to use in my code works perfectly fine when I type it in to the console.

EDIT 3!

**Tiers of output from direct access through console**:

```
1) layer -> Object
2) layer.features -> Object
3) layer.features[0] -> Object
4) layer.features[0].attributes -> Object
5) layer.features[0].attributes.name -> <the string I'm looking for>
OR
6) layer.features[0].attributes['name'] works the same as above
```

**Output from hardcoded script**:

```
1) layer -> Object
2) layer.features -> []
3) layer.features[0] -> undefined
etc...
```

Comment: **What** do you get when you display `console.log(layer)`? The answer to this question clearly hinges on the structure of the `layer` object. For instance, you're assuming the resulting `layer` object has a property called `features`, but there's none listed here: http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.10/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer-js.html

Comment: Can you post console.log()? Maybe JSON stringified if your browser doesn't output it like this already.

Comment: We also need to see the structure of layer.features.

Comment: Well, now we know that there is a `features` property and it has one entry, but we know nothing about what's in that entry. Can you show a JSON stringified version as pdknsk suggests? So we can get the full picture?

Comment: Working on it now, apparently there are some circular references.  Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: I've updated the original post with the relevant information.

Comment: I doubt it makes a difference, but have you tried to access it with `object['name']` instead of `object.name`?

Comment: Yep, again that works fine from the console but in the script it does not work.

Comment: Do you have any of the object names as variable names in the script? Do you get a different output with `console.log(layer['features'])`? Obviously the output fails because the list is empty when run from the script.

Comment: I tried layer['features'], it returns an empty array as well.  Also, I changed all of my variables to (hopefully) unique names and the same thing continued to happen.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to see the properties provided you're following the path to them correctly. Your full expression is `layer.features[0].attributes.name`. What you've posted so far tells us that the `layer.features` and `layer.features[0]` parts are right, but we'd have to know what's in `layer.features[0]` to know whether it has an `attributes` property, etc.

One thing that jumps out is that `attributes` is plural and then you're accessing a property on it directly. The plural *suggests* it may be an array, and so perhaps you need to look at a subscript?

For this stuff, I find nothing beats a debugger. You can use one drill down into the `layer` object and find out exactly what's in there, and usually when you do that you even see the path to the point you've expanded to. There are debuggers for every major browser out there:

- Chrome and Safari have "Dev Tools" built in (on Chrome Ctrl+Shift+I will open the panel)
- Firefox has the excellent [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) add-in
- IE has the free edition of [Visual Studio.Net](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Web/) (and IE8 and above have some built-in tools as well)

**Edit**: This part of your updated question is interesting:

> 2) `layer.features -> []`
>   
> 3) `layer.features[0] -> undefined`

That suggests that either A) `features` is an empty array, or B) `features` is a *sparse* array that doesn't have an index `0`. All JavaScript arrays are sparse (they're not really arrays at all), so you might try:

```
var name;
for (name in layer.features) {
    console.log(name + ": " + layer.features[name]);
}
```

Comment: Yep, the solution is literally just one click away in Chrome Developer Tools. Or two, to expand the features array.

Comment: Using the Chrome dev tools which is why I know the information is there in the first place.  As mentioned in console I can access this data, but doing the same thing in my code it is broken.

Comment: I'm having similar issue, when I give console.log(layer.features.length) it showing 0, but when I'm giving same in firebug console then length is showing as 10(which is actual length features array, I'm able to see in firebug).What might be reason ? before creating 'layer' object is layer.features.length is calling ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to study the format of your object.  This is the long way around, but try this:

```
console.log(layer.features);
console.log(layer.features[0]);
console.log(layer.features[0].attributes);
console.log(layer.features[0].attributes.name);
```

Somewhere down the line you'll get an error, and that will tell you where your problem is.  I would guess, after seeing your current log, that either `attributes` or `name` does not exist (at least not in the format you think they do).  (of course, it's better/easier to use the drill-down in firebug for this, but the snippet above will get you started.)